# Same server time on all devices, Ionic/ Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We have created an app, which is based on Time.

We used this code to get system time.

```
{new Date ()}
```

Some of our players hacked, to change the system / device time, in this way they can play the past game.

Now, we applied server api to google cloud engine, but there's a delay to fetch the time from api 1 to 5 seconds. How. Can we matched the time of all the players and then fire en event on time...

Technologies i used, Ionic Framework 4.0, Angular, Google Cloud, Firebase.

Thanks